# How to parallelize matrix slicing by conditional indexing in R using DoParallel?

Tags: r, matrix, parallel-processing, distributed-computing, doparallel

I have trying parallelize for loop in the following code snippet:

```
t0 <- Sys.time()
x <- matrix(runif(200*1000, 1, 5), nrow =200, ncol = 1000)
print(Sys.time() - t0 )
t0 <- Sys.time()
u <- unique(as.vector(x))
print(Sys.time() - t0 )
print(length(u))
utransformed <- asinh(u)
uindex <- seq(from = 1, to = length(u), by = 1)
t0 <- Sys.time()
for (hh in uindex)
{
     x[x == u[hh] ] = utransformed[hh]
}
print(Sys.time() - t0 )
```

I tried parallelizing for loop my making modifications as follows:

```
library(doParallel)
#setup parallel backend to use many processors
cores=detectCores()
print(cores)
cl <- makeCluster(cores[1]-1) #not to overload your computer
registerDoParallel(cl)
t0 <- Sys.time()
x <- matrix(runif(200*1000, 1, 5), nrow =200, ncol = 1000)
print(Sys.time() - t0 )
t0 <- Sys.time()
u <- unique(as.vector(x))
print(Sys.time() - t0 )
print(length(u))
utransformed <- asinh(u)
uindex <- seq(from = 1, to = length(u), by = 1)
subsetter <- function(xh, uh, uth, h)
{
    xh[xh == uh[h]] = uth[h]
}
t0 <- Sys.time()
foreach(i = uindex,.combine=cbind)  %dopar% (
    subsetter(x,u,utransformed,i)
)
print(Sys.time() - t0 )
```

This definitely doesn't seem to work and I am not sure how can I achieve parallelizing my `for` loop to change some values of my matrix `x` by conditional indexing. Any help or guidance in this matter is much appreciated.

Comment: You might want to look at my blog post at https://privefl.github.io/blog/a-guide-to-parallelism-in-r/#filling-something-in-parallel.

Comment: Thanks, while your examples are very useful, `FBM` matrices do not operate in the following ways : `mat[mat > 4]`. Trying to use `mat[mat > 4]`  gave me error stating:

Error in mat > 4 : 
  comparison (6) is possible only for atomic and list types

Comment: You can access the R matrix with `mat[]`. Anyway, indexing based on values from `mat` and filling new values to `mat`, you don't see any problem of doing this in parallel?

Comment: That's what I am saying. When I attempt to do this in parallel, I get the error :

Error in mat > 4 : comparison (6) is possible only for atomic and list types

Comment: Here is the code that I used as a minimal example: https://gist.github.com/gravitogen/f0a8943f3b837b3685471e7ebc6833ca